# Custom controller reuses Magento front name

Tags: magento2, controllers, routing

I've added custom controller under magento `frontName` and it works.

My `routes.xml`:

```
    ...
        <router id="standard">

            <route id="customer" frontName="customer">
                <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]"/>
            </route>

        </router>
    ...
```

Path to controller is `[Vendor]/Customer/Controller/Address/EditAjax` and path in url is `/customer/address/editajax`. Is there any drawback or possibility of errors with native magento controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, we can reuse the existing route. However, in some cases, our new controllers need to check the authentication. In your case, we need to check customer authentication. If we don't check anything and write the bad code, anyone can do the CRUD operations.

Luckily, Magento builds some abstract classes for checking security. In this case, our custom class should be extended from `Magento\Customer\Controller\Address`.

Comment: thank you for complete answer!
+1 for iheritance hint